# How do i merge multiple files together for a website?

Tags: html, css, webserver, jpeg

I have a folder containing multiple files that compose of my website, but all different extensions, meaning that in order to access my website on another computer, the entire folder is needed(I might be wrong on this point though). This folder contains files that are jpeg, html, css, and png, and my website is written in html and css containing images of png and jpeg extension.

How do I merge multiple files together for a website?

Comment: You need to learn about web servers and HTTP.  You're completely misunderstanding how the web works.

Comment: what are you trying to say? make it clear. for viewing your webpage on someone's else computer, you need to upload your files on server.

Comment: i literally just want to be able to email someone my website link, and they can open it without missing information since at the moment i have to the links ive used in my code of images, and also my css code

Comment: @user6842389: You need to publish your site to a web server.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to drag your folder to https://www.bitballoon.com/

Comment: no, sorry i think i haven't explained the motive of WHY i want to do this, i DO know i have to purchase a domain in the web server so my site becomes public but all i want to do at the moment is send the html link or whatever extension is needed to the file so someone can open it without missing images or no css graphics

Comment: thank you @CalebEby

Comment: So @user6842389 did you upload it to a server? Bitballoon and Netlify are free, and you can put your site there for free in less than a minute.

Comment: Well then just zip or rar the folder, and send that ... but be aware that email attachment size is usually limited in the low double digit MB; if it is any larger than that, use a service like dropbox.

Comment: @user6842389 You can't put a link directly to the files on your computer unless you want to run your computer 24/7

Answer (score 0):

To make your website publicly available, you need to upload it to a server.

It is important to understand how a client (like a browser) and a server interact:

```
client                                                       server
      request for index.html ----------------------------->
             <------------------------------ ok, here is index.html
      reading index.html file
      request styles.css --------------------------------->
             <------------------------------ ok, here is styles.css
      request image.jpg ---------------------------------->
             <------------------------------- ok, here is image.jpg
```

So now that you can see that loading a website is a back-in-forth process, you can understand that the server needs each of these files.

So to answer your question, you just need to upload the entire folder to whichever host so that people who visit your site can have images and css.

Some options for free hosting are:

- [BitBalloon (easy, drag and drop folder)](https://www.bitballoon.com/)
- [Netlify (easy, drag and drop folder)](https://www.netlify.com/)
- [GitHub Pages (a bit harder)](https://pages.github.com/)